# graphing years of server temperature data

Tags: php

I have a couple of HP M5 servers that I've been collecting temperature reference data for a year now.

The problem I have is with graphing this with PHP.

I've tried half a dozen methods from Google chart to SWF charts and JS but all seem cumbersome due to the large amount of data.

How could I graph this data successfully and easily?<

At this time i am using a graph setup like this:
[image]

Comment: what features were you looking for in a charting solution? Drilldown, date ranges, etc?

Comment: i gave a graph like the one added to the post. i would like to have time/temperature corespondence as the most important thing.

Comment: "but all seem cumbersome due to the large amount of data" - then reducing the amount of data sounds like an option. Take the average of one hour or one day or whatever a reasonable resolution would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/doc/rrdtool.en.html RRDTool to graph temperature and everything else going on in a server.

Comment: yea. but i've got all data in a MYSQL database

Answer (score 0):

Gnuplot is a great tool for on-demand plotting.